# css and page layout like FB and similar sites

Tags: css, html

ANyone know a good tutorial on how to to use css+html to define a layout similar to FB?

I am looking for a good example on how to have a header that is 100% and then a middle column as a body that is about 700px wide with one column on each side.

Updated:

I am not trying to understand CSS layout with div. Just trying to see if there is one way  or common a way to do it

I am interested to know  (using FB as an exmaple) .. how they are able to have those horizontal backgrounds and then have their content lined up in three columns or it is lined up in the middle.

Comment: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: This is really trivial, if you don't know how to layout CSS then learn it. tutorial specific to a specific layout, really?

Comment: I was just curious if I was doing it right and seeing how other designers are doing it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="styleSheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">Hello</div>
    <div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
    <div id="content">Content</div>
    <div id="sidebar-right">Right</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the css:

```
body, html{
    width:      100%;
    height:     100%;
    margin:     0;
    padding:    0;
}

#header{
    width:      100%;
padding-left:   200px;
    height:     50px;
    background: #0000FF;
}

#sidebar{
    float:      left;
    width:      200px;
    height:     100%;
    background: #FF0000;
}

#content{
    float:      left;
    width:      700px;
    height:     100%;
    background: #00FF00;
}

#sidebar-right{
    margin-left:900px;
    height:     100%;
    background: #FFFF00;
}
```

Comment: @magic-c0d3r I've updated the code now so that this happens.

Comment: if I want the content in the header to line up with the content in the body, do I jsut add a div in the header and set magin to auto?

Comment: @magic-c0d3r I've fixed this by adding a padding in the header div of 200px, the size of the sidebar.

Comment: why not put another div inside the header as a container? container would be width of 700px and margin:auto?

Comment: You could do that if you wanted but usually it is considered bad to have too many divs.

Answer (score 2):

First define a wrapper class that is the width you want your page to be. Set it's margin to `auto` (at least on the left and right) so it will be centered in the page. You said 700px, so:

```
.wrapper
{
    width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Now you need your three columns, one in the middle and one on each side. Assuming that the left and right side are not the same size (just to make things clear), do something like this:

```
#left
{
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

#middle
{
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
}

#right
{
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

Now add the 100% width header:

```
#header
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

And you can setup your page like so:

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
         Your header here
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Here is this example with arbitrary background colors on each div, so you can see where they are:

http://jsfiddle.net/grwjy/

This is just a simple example but hopefully will get you on the right track.